# Why does my function "hangs"

Tags: python, mysql

```
def retCursor():
    host = "localhost"
    user = "disappearedng"

    db = "gupan_crawling3"
    conn = MySQLdb.connect( host=host, user=user, passwd=passwd, db=db)
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    return cursor
singleCur = retCursor()


def checkTemplateBuilt(netlocH):
    """Used by crawler specifically, this check directly whether template has been built"""
    singleCur.execute( """SELECT templateBuilt FROM templateEnough WHERE netloc=%s""", [ netlocH])
    r = singleCur.fetchone()
    if r:
        if bool( r[0]):
            return True
    return False
```

Hi everyone I am currently using MySQLdb. For some reason, after perhaps 30 mins of running my app comes to a complete halt. It appears that this function is blocking me. (DOn't know for what reason)

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/multiprocessing/process.py", line 231, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "/mount/950gb/gupan5/disappearedng_temp/code_temp_NEWBRANCH/gupan5-yahoo/crawling/templateCrawling/TemplateCrawler/crawler/crawler.py", line 117, in run
    self.get_check_put()
  File "/mount/950gb/gupan5/disappearedng_temp/code_temp_NEWBRANCH/gupan5-yahoo/crawling/templateCrawling/TemplateCrawler/crawler/crawler.py", line 66, in get_check_put
    if not self.checkLinkCrawlability(linkS, priority):
  File "/mount/950gb/gupan5/disappearedng_temp/code_temp_NEWBRANCH/gupan5-yahoo/crawling/templateCrawling/TemplateCrawler/crawler/crawler.py", line 53, in checkLinkCrawlability
    if checkTemplateBuilt( getNetLoc( link)):
  File "/mount/950gb/gupan5/disappearedng_temp/code_temp_NEWBRANCH/gupan5-yahoo/crawling/templateCrawling/TemplateCrawler/publicapi/publicfunc.py", line 71, in checkTemplateBuilt
    singleCur.execute( """SELECT templateBuilt FROM templateEnough WHERE netloc=%s""", [ netlocH])
  File "/var/lib/python-support/python2.6/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 153, in execute
    r = self._query(query)
KeyboardInterrupt
```

Btw this is the table:

```
CREATE TABLE templateEnough( 
    `netloc` INT(32) unsigned NOT NULL,   
    `count` SMALLINT(32) unsigned NOT NULL,
    `templateBuilt` TINYINT(1) unsigned DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY ( netloc )
) ENGINE=MEMORY DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
;
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

There might be a lock on the table preventing the query from completing.

Comment: Really? How do I determine that?

Comment: For innodb, you could use "show enginge innodb status", see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-monitors.html. Not sure about memory engine.

Answer (score 1):

Try logging the query string to a file right before you execute it.
Then when you think it is hung, you can look at the query and see if it works manually

Comment: You mean just printing out the SQL statement before the cursor executing it? ok will do. Doubt it has anything to do with the query though.

Comment: if you know which query the program is hanging on, then you can run the same query in the mysqlclient to see what happens there. You can try variations of the query. It looks like a simple enough query, so the reason for hanging may be quite strange. divide and conquer

Answer (score 0):

According to your traceback, you interrupted the script during the execution of `checkTemplateBuilt`, not `enoughPassedForTemplate`.

I think the problem lies in a different part of the code; maybe there is an infinite loop somewhere? Maybe in the `run` function?

Comment: I re-edited my paste. I don't think I would have an infinite loop anywhere.